# Calculating age using date of birth stored in the database

Tags: datediff, google-app-maker

does anyone know if DATEDIFF function is working in Google App Maker - Calculated SQL models? I would like to calculate the age by reporting the date of birth from the database at the current date. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`DATEDIFF` does work however it's not going to give you as accurate an age as `TIMESTAMPDIFF`. Use this instead:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date_of_birth, CURDATE()) AS age from your_table;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
I tried in Google App Maker – Calculated model – SQL query, but every time I received "syntax error...”
My query with MySQL 5.7 syntax was: SELECT DATEDIFF (day, CURRENT_DATE, MyDateBirthNameField) AS DestinationNameField FROM MyModelName 

and My query with Standard SQL syntax was: SELECT DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE, DATE MyDateBirthNameField, DAY) AS DestinationNameField FROM MyModelName

Comment: You're getting a syntax error because you aren't following proper syntax for MySQL DATEDIFF. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner. I used the function TIMESTAMPDIFF and it works. Thank you all for your help.